# Get SRC from IMG with Class, using DOM php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to get the src from this a:

```
<a class="poster" href="#">
<img itemprop="image" id="upload_poster" alt="alt" title="title" class="shadow"  
src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/z99yU71wH7JBHZX4tQ3XzPG521M.jpg"/>    
</a>
```

Can any help me?
I've this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($url);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$tags = $xpath->query('//img[@class="shadow"]');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   $tag->getAttribute('src');
}

//Guardo todo en un array
$data = array('moviedb' => $tag, 'msg' => 'success');
```

I don't want echo, i need to save the data in a array.

This return: [Object][Object]

Comment: You're clearly getting the `src` in the loop, but you're not doing anything to it. What is really the question here, how to add each source to an array ?

Comment: I need to add the source to an array, yes. But, i can't

Comment: your loop doesn't make sense, the `src` string isn't assignment inside the array. if you want each image tag's source then the assignment of that string should be inside the loop continually pushing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you need to include the data that will populate the array:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   $src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
   $data[] = array('moviedb' => $src, 'msg' => 'success');
}
```

The result would then look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [moviedb] => https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/z99yU71wH7JBHZX4tQ3XzPG521M.jpg
            [msg] => success
        )
)
```

Comment: Ok, but no work. I've another line after:

    `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: I'm trying to get these src, from a URL. This is the full code: 

Comprobarthemoviedb.php: http://ideone.com/YxyAj3

`$url = $_GET["url"];` it's come to a custom_field from Wordpress editor, and the result of parser, go to another custom_field-> `input[name='caratulapelicula']`

ajaxmoviedb.js : http://ideone.com/G47x1O